# Error while saving ParseRelation

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm having some issues while trying to save a ParseRelation. I've tried creating the ParseUser first (I thought that was the problem) but it continued to happen.

*Situation*: I have 2 tables, one is User (Parse.com default) and a second one called Teams. Inside the latter, there's a ParseRelation to User. After saveInBackground is triggered I check the DataBrowser and I can see that the team was in fact created but the players added not in the relation.

My code:

```
ParseObject newTeam = new ParseObject(Constants.TABLE_TEAMS);
newTeam.put(Constants.ATTRIB_TEAM_NAME, nombreEquipo);
// FIXME ParseRelation not being saved
ParseRelation<ParseUser> playersRelation = newTeam
        .getRelation(Constants.ATTRIB_TEAM_PLAYERS);

// Get Users from ListView
for (int i = 0; i < invitedPlayers.size(); i++) {
    ParseUser pu = (ParseUser) viewPlayerList.getItemAtPosition(i);
    playersRelation.add(pu);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,
            "Player being added: "
                    + pu.get(Constants.ATTRIB_USER_NAME));
}
newTeam.put(Constants.ATTRIB_TEAM_PLAYERS, playersRelation);
newTeam.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // setResult(RESULT_OK);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Team created.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "ParseException: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

});
```

Any ideas ? I've read the docs and also checked a few samples but can't seem to find out what's the problem.

Edit: Using Parse.com v1.5.0 and Android 4.4.2

Comment: Is this a many-to-many relationship? Can a player be a member of more than one team? If not, I would go for pointers instead of parserelations.

Comment: Yeah, a Player can be part of many Teams. I tried using an Array on Team and it worked but I still would like to know why Rel. isn't working if possible